# Loading app from eclipse very very slow during development

Tags: android

H,
I'm trying to write a puzzle app for kids.  The graphics are all high res HD, very big apk file.  It takes for every to load during each update. Is there any way I can sped up the transfer rate of the apk file from eclipse to my device?

Comment: Switch to small low-res graphics or placeholders during development and then switch back to the proper graphics afterwards?

Comment: am looking towards the same!!!

Comment: Put the images on the SDCard and load them from there during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator is slow.
As @bladiblah says, try low-res graphics for development. You should just be able to set the emulator device to a low setting like QVGA and make sure you have an appropiate subdirectory in /res
You may also try to run [androidx86](http://www.android-x86.org/) in a virtual machine (e.g. virtualbox) as the performance is much better. However be aware that androidx86 is a fork, so it's not the exact same code that's run on a device.